# Delete one character at End of File in PERL

Tags: html, perl, jsonp

So I have encountered a problem while programming with PERL. I use a foreach loop to get some data out of the hash, so it has to loop through it.

**The Code:**

```
foreach $title (keys %FilterSPRINTHASH) {
    $openSP = $FilterSPRINTHASH{$title}{openSP};
    $estSP = $FilterSPRINTHASH{$title}{estSP};
    $line = "'$title':{'openSP' : $openSP, 'estSP' : $estSP}\n";
    print $outfile "$line\n";
}
```

The thing is, that I am creating a seperate File with the PERL's writting to a file expression, which will be a JSONP text (later used for HTML).

Back to the problem:

As JSONP requires comma's "," after every line that is not the last one, i had to put a comma at the end of line, **however** when the last line comes in, I have to remove the comma.

I have tried with CHOP function, but not sure where to put it, since if I put it at the end of foreach, it will just chop the comma in $line, but this wont chop it in the new file I created.

I have also tried with while (<>) statement, with no success.

Any ideas appreaciated.

BR

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON` module is far less error prone; no need to reinvent the wheel

```
use JSON;

print $outfile encode_json(\%FilterSPRINTHASH), "\n";
```

Comment: This would be really good, but I have not noticed the useage for JSONP. The last letter is importmant, because JSONP allows you to communicate with your HTML without the Web Server. While JSON does not allow that. Thanks though

Comment: @user3533253 JSONP also uses JSON, so that would be `"$callback(". encode_json(\%FilterSPRINTHASH) .")"`

Comment: Hello mpapec! So to fully understand it for myself - with adding the callback("encode_json(....).") PERL knows that I want to get the JSONP format automaticly?

Comment: @user3533253 No, this just manually adds JSONP decoration around JSON.

Comment: EDIT: I understand it. $callback is probably the JSONP title that you have to give, while creating a JSONP format. For example:  `jsonpOBJECT ({...  $callback = jsonpOBJECT`   - or?

Comment: @user3533253 I'm afraid you're lacking necessary understanding to differentiate between JSON and JSONP, and that is already out of scope of your original question.

Comment: the difference in syntax is the "( )" at the begining and in the end. And JSONP also uses some sort of a name, which you can reference to in HTML for example.  So JSONP looks like: `jsonOBJECT ({ "year": { "y2014" = 2014, "y2013"}});`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is the last iteration of the loop, then remove the comma from line.

So something like

```
my $count = keys %FilterSPRINTHASH; #Get number of keys (scalar context)
my $loop_count = 1; #Use a variable to count number of iteration

foreach $title (keys %FilterSPRINTHASH){
    $openSP = $FilterSPRINTHASH{$title}{openSP};
    $estSP = $FilterSPRINTHASH{$title}{estSP};
    $line = "'$title':{'openSP' : $openSP, 'estSP' : $estSP}\n";
    if($loop_count == $count){
        #this is the last iteration, so remove the comma from line
        $line =~ s/,+$//;
    }
    print $outfile "$line\n";
    $loop_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would approach this by storing your output in an array and then joining that with the line separators you wish:

```
my @output; # storage for output
foreach $title (keys %FilterSPRINTHASH) {
  # create each line
  my $line = sprintf "'%s':{'openSP' : %s, 'estSP' : %s}", $title, $FilterSPRINTHASH{$title}{openSP}, $FilterSPRINTHASH{$title}{estSP};
  # and put it in the output container
  push @output, $line;
}
# join all outputlines with comma and newline and then output
print $outfile (join ",\n", @output);
```